# Train a neural network with input as sliding windows of a matrix with Tensorflow / Keras, and memory issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, rolling-computation, sliding-window

I have a dataset which is a big matrix of shape (100 000, 2 000).

I would like to train my Tensorflow neural network with **all the possible sliding windows/submatrices of shape (16, 2000)** of this big matrix.

[image]

I use:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

A.shape  # (100000, 2000)  ie 100k x 2k matrix
X = view_as_windows(A, (16, 2000)).reshape((-1, 16, 2000, 1))
X.shape   # (99985, 16, 2000, 1)
...
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=4, epochs=8)
```

Unfortunately, this leads to a memory problem:

> W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of ... exceeds 10% of system memory.

This is normal, since X has ~ 100k * 16 * 2k coefficients, i.e. more than 3 billion coefficients!

But in fact, it is a waste of memory to load X in memory because it is **highly redundant**: it is made of sliding windows of shape (16, 2000) over `A`.

**Question: how to train a neural network with input being *all sliding windows of width 16* over a 100k x 2k matrix, without wasting memory?**

The documentation of [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) states indeed that it's costly in memory:

> One should be very careful with rolling views when it comes to memory usage. Indeed, although a ‘view’ has the same memory footprint as its base array, the actual array that emerges when this ‘view’ is used in a computation is generally a (much) larger array than the original, especially for 2-dimensional arrays and above.
>
> For example, let us consider a 3 dimensional array of size (100, 100, 100) of float64. [...] the hypothetical size of the rolling view (if one was to reshape the view for example) would be 8*(100-3+1)**3*3**3 which is about 203 MB! The scaling becomes even worse as the dimension of the input array becomes larger.

---

Edit: `timeseries_dataset_from_array` is exactly what I'm looking for except that it works only for 1D sequences:

```
import tensorflow
import tensorflow.keras.preprocessing
x = list(range(100))
x2 = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, None, 10, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, seed=None, start_index=None, end_index=None)
for b in x2:
    print(b)
```

and it doesn't work for 2D arrays:

```
x = np.array(range(90)).reshape(6, 15)
print(x)
x2 = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, None, (6, 3), sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, seed=None, start_index=None, end_index=None)
# does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generator to yield examples on fly instead of storing them in memory.

You can either write custom `generator` or generator provided by keras like `timeseries_dataset_from_array` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array)) that can yield windows as well with help of options like `sequence_stride`.

For custom generator, you can do something like

```
def generator_custom(df3):
    for idex,row in df3.iterrows():
            #some preprocessing
            yield X,y
```

And then you can use tf.data to take batch of 128/64/32 as

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: generator_custom(df_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(128,drop_remainder=True)
```

**Replying you comment about two dimensions**

Just an example (I scale 100000,2000 to 1000.200 for example, feel free to change them)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(200000)).reshape(1000, 200)
x2 = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, None, 16, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128)
```

That gives you something like

> shapes (128, 16, 200)
>
> shapes (128, 16, 200)

Which is what you want (16*2000), right? (remember we have 200 just to showing purpose)

Comment: I just tried `timeseries_dataset_from_array` @A.B, and it's *exactly* what I'm looking for, except that it is for 1D array, and my input is 2D. Do you know an equivalent of `timeseries_dataset_from_array` that produces sliding 2D windows over a 2D array?

Comment: Thanks @A.B. It helps a lot; there is still a problem: the neural network expects an input of size `(..., 16, 2000, 1)` instead of `(..., 16, 2000)` which is produced by `timeseries_dataset_from_array`. Do you know how to do this? I posted more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099569/reshape-a-tensorflow-dataset-preprocessed-with-timeseries-dataset-from-array

Comment: Give a try to Lescurel's answer to this question there ( relating mapping), I feel it would work.

Comment: @Basj feel free to accept it as an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

If using Tensorflow, you can use a Tensorflow Dataset and map a preprocessing function over the data like so:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

A.shape # (100000, 2000)

def get_window(starting_idx):
    """Extract a window from A of shape (16, 2000) as a tf.Tensor"""
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(A[starting_idx : starting_idx + 16])

# Make dataset for actual data
data_ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(A.shape[0] - 16)
data_ds = data_ds.map(get_window)

# Make dataset for labels
label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Y)

# Zip them into one dataset
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((data_ds, label_ds))

# Pre-batch the dataset
ds = ds.batch(4)

# Sanity check for batch size
for batch, label in ds:
    print(batch.shape)    # (4, 16, 2000, 1)
    break

# Now call .fit() without batch size
model.fit(ds, epochs=8)
```

Defining a function for extracting each window and mapping this over an existing dataset should solve your memory problem, as it should allow the windows to be formed only when needed.

This is in general one of the best ways to handle data when working with Tensorflow, and you can handle large amounts of data this way.

For more information, see [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and [tensorflow.org/guide/data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @thehumaneraser. I tried it, but it doesn't solve the memory issue: calling `from_tensor_slices` on the result of `view_as_windows` still uses all the memory needed by `view_as_windows` (see my edited question with more details about this). Can you add more details about what you had in mind to avoid `view_as_windows`?

Comment: I edited the original answer to expand to a more usable workflow with a tf.data.Dataset