# VertexAI online prediction with timeseries data sliding windows

Tags: gcloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

I already have a trained model (that does classification) that takes as input timeseries of shape [2500, 3]. I exported it on vertex as a custom model and created a public endpoint from it.
I can request it with other timeseries and get them classified without any problem.
But my issue is that, I actually need to make a lot of request: One instance of my object (on which I want to classify every timestamp) has a size of ~ [2 000 000, 3]. If I want to get a prediction at each timestamp, I'd need to take sliding windows (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088246/train-a-neural-network-with-input-as-sliding-windows-of-a-matrix-with-tensorflow)), and therefore I could have a lot of windows to predict (depending on the gap I choose between two consecutive windows, right now i'm using 500).

So I'm wondering, shouldn't I have some kind of pipeline on gcloud in which the sliding windows - and the classification is computed? Because right now I'm really limited by the 1.5MB (which is around ~10 windows of data for me) max payload size per request for vertex public endpoints. If so, which tool is designed to do this kind of stuff?